# Return top n of an array for each hash type in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes which looks like this:

```
[
  {:name=>"CCC_010112.JPG", :type=>"CCC", :date=>"120101"},
  {:name=>"BBB_050112.JPG", :type=>"BBB", :date=>"120501"},
  {:name=>"BBB_040112.JPG", :type=>"BBB", :date=>"120401"},
  {:name=>"BBB_030112.JPG", :type=>"BBB", :date=>"120301"},
  {:name=>"BBB_020112.JPG", :type=>"BBB", :date=>"120201"},
  {:name=>"BBB_010112.JPG", :type=>"BBB", :date=>"120101"},
  {:name=>"AAA_040112.JPG", :type=>"AAA", :date=>"120401"},
  {:name=>"AAA_030112.JPG", :type=>"AAA", :date=>"120301"},
  {:name=>"AAA_020112.JPG", :type=>"AAA", :date=>"120201"},
]
```

I am trying to capture the first three of each type. (e.g., my results should yield the array bove, only cutting out the bottom two of the "BBB" elements. I tried variants of the following:

```
puts a.each{|e| e[:type]}.take(3) #Shows top 3 of all
```

Comment: What do you mean by "top 3"?  First 3 that happen to come up? Or do the elements have some ordering property you haven't told us about?

Comment: What does "top" mean? Can you use `group_by` to separate the... uh... groups?

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm not familiar with group_by, but will look into it

Comment: @pjs - the list is already reverse-sorted. I need the first 3 that come up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a more efficient way, but off the top:

```
a = [
{:name=>"CCC_010112.JPG", :type=>"CCC", :date=>"120101"},
{:name=>"BBB_050112.JPG", :type=>"BBB", :date=>"120501"},
{:name=>"BBB_040112.JPG", :type=>"BBB", :date=>"120401"},
{:name=>"BBB_030112.JPG", :type=>"BBB", :date=>"120301"},
{:name=>"BBB_020112.JPG", :type=>"BBB", :date=>"120201"},
{:name=>"BBB_010112.JPG", :type=>"BBB", :date=>"120101"},
{:name=>"AAA_040112.JPG", :type=>"AAA", :date=>"120401"},
{:name=>"AAA_030112.JPG", :type=>"AAA", :date=>"120301"},
{:name=>"AAA_020112.JPG", :type=>"AAA", :date=>"120201"}
]

a_types = (a.collect { |e| e[:type] }).uniq
a_top3 = []
a_types.each { |t| a_top3 << (a.select { |e| e[:type] == t }).take(3) }
a_top3.flatten!
```

Comment: The first is only returning 3 elements, but I need the first 3 of each element type.

Comment: actually.. that worked perfectly.. but I need the array, not the puts

Comment: I changed it to create an array.

Answer (score 3):

I would do using [`Enumerable#chunk`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk), as in the array all different types like `'CCC'`, `'BBB'` etc are already clubbed together. If they were scattered, [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), to club different types of hashes first.

```
a = [
       {:name=>"CCC_010112.JPG", :type=>"CCC", :date=>"120101"},
       {:name=>"BBB_050112.JPG", :type=>"BBB", :date=>"120501"},
       {:name=>"BBB_040112.JPG", :type=>"BBB", :date=>"120401"},
       {:name=>"BBB_030112.JPG", :type=>"BBB", :date=>"120301"},
       {:name=>"BBB_020112.JPG", :type=>"BBB", :date=>"120201"},
       {:name=>"BBB_010112.JPG", :type=>"BBB", :date=>"120101"},
       {:name=>"AAA_040112.JPG", :type=>"AAA", :date=>"120401"},
       {:name=>"AAA_030112.JPG", :type=>"AAA", :date=>"120301"},
       {:name=>"AAA_020112.JPG", :type=>"AAA", :date=>"120201"}
    ]

final_top3_ary = a.chunk { |hash| hash[:type] }.flat_map { |_,ary| ary.take(3) }

final_top3_ary
# => [{:name=>"CCC_010112.JPG", :type=>"CCC", :date=>"120101"},
#     {:name=>"BBB_050112.JPG", :type=>"BBB", :date=>"120501"},
#     {:name=>"BBB_040112.JPG", :type=>"BBB", :date=>"120401"},
#     {:name=>"BBB_030112.JPG", :type=>"BBB", :date=>"120301"},
#     {:name=>"AAA_040112.JPG", :type=>"AAA", :date=>"120401"},
#     {:name=>"AAA_030112.JPG", :type=>"AAA", :date=>"120301"},
#     {:name=>"AAA_020112.JPG", :type=>"AAA", :date=>"120201"}]
```

Comment: This would look a lot nicer if you used braces for the block passed to `chunk` to create a one-liner (in my opinion). +1 anyway :)

Comment: @MarkThomas Yes.. Indeed :-)

Comment: Very nice, @Arup +1. You mentioned the use of `group_by`, but you might be more specific: one need only change `chunk` to `group_by` in your expression.  Alternatively, one could first `a.sort_by {|h} h[:type]}`, which has the possible side benefit of ordering the elements of the output array alphabeticaly by `:type`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You mentioned it more nicer than I could be. I hope future readers would take the hints from the comment itself. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned in comments that your list is already reverse-sorted, we can use just this:

```
top3_of_each = a.inject([]) do |acc, h|
  acc << h if acc.length < 3 || h[:type] != acc[acc.length-3][:type]
  acc
end
```

If the list is not reverse-sorted, then we need to do more work on grouping hashes by types and finding top 3 for each type.